# C++ Hello World not showing output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Learning C++ with Programming Principles and Practice Using c++, I done this

```
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello programming!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

First I got warning with "PDB files not found" after debugging. Then I solved that, and getting this,

```
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Chai\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FLTK testing\Debug\FLTK testing.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FLTK testing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[7320] FLTK testing.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

But I'm still not getting the output showing "Hello programming!". I have tried `cin.get()` too but no result. Any advice??

Comment: cout is in a header file called #include <iostream>

Comment: tried, same thing :/

Comment: How are you running the program?  If you are just double clicking on it, it will just run and disappear.  If you have a very fast machine, you may not even see it.  If you run from a cmd prompt, you may get something.

Comment: @QuentinUK iostream is included in the special header he uses (it is from a C++ book)

Comment: use getch(); just before the return 0;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **flush** call:

```
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello programming!\n";
    cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: added, didn't work. =(